# listagg using when overflow of varchar2 occures - what to do?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Could somebody advice what to do when using listagg leads to varchar2 overflow because of lots of aggregated strings (during aggregation in SQL query via Group etc.) in One field?

I use report (It just ONE SQL query) where I aggregate Phone Codes by ZoneName (Country etc.) and some of them have tons of codes for one Zone - so I could get "oveflow" error cause listagg using varchar2 that have 32767 limitation.

So what to do in such situations? Rewrite query and use cursors? Is there a workaround to detect "oveflow" and split, for example, such "BIG FIELD" in TWO rows so that in every one there would be enough space for "BIG list of Codes"???

Because I'm on 10gR2 now I'm using "Tab to string" technic from Tom Kyte.
it uses Type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_varchar2_tab AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
```

And proc, that converts from Table of Varchar2 to One String that has 32767 chars limitation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tab_to_string (p_varchar2_tab  IN  t_varchar2_tab,
                                          p_delimiter     IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  l_string     VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN p_varchar2_tab.FIRST .. p_varchar2_tab.LAST LOOP
    IF i != p_varchar2_tab.FIRST THEN
      l_string := l_string || p_delimiter;
    END IF;
    l_string := l_string || p_varchar2_tab(i);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_string;
END tab_to_string;
/
```

And for the present Moment I got "overflow" error in my case.

I suppose that listagg proc will have the same problem because of using Varchar2.

Any advices?

**UPD:** I ONLY need this (aggregation of codes in One field during generation of Report) to OUTPUT data for Report (in .pdf or while Printing). In Database all the Data is Normalized.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to normalise the data so that you have each string n a separate row then the number of items you can have is limited to te database not a single field.

tab_to_string is only useful for output and I doubt you want to see a field > 32K characters.

Comment: I have Normalized data - codes are Hierarcally located in table and THEN aggregated via connect by prior. 
And YES I Need TO Output them in One Field in Report!
And exactly I have One row with Zone Name, It's Price and ALL Codes for this Zones in ONE field and it could be rather long when printing.

Comment: How do you print just in the delimited form or do you add carriage returns at some place?

Comment: I print as a Table - coulmns, rows. Almost the same As I see when i run the query on DB directly.